# How to write HTML response in a file using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Can any one help me how to save HTML response (including screen images) from View Results Tree listener using JMeter?

I can store the results in csv but my main objective is to store the screen images that are displayed in view results tree

The screenshot name should be stored under step name (eg: TC002 Account Menu)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add JSR223PostProcessor and save response body to the file.
For example like this:

```
    File file = new File(pathToYourFile);
    FileWriter fstream= new FileWriter(file,true);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
    out.close();
    fstream.close();
```

If you want each answer to be saved in a different file, you will need to add code to create the files and add them a new uniq name.

**UPD**
One way to save each response in your own file is to generate the name depending on the value of the counter like this:
(Using JMeter Functions)

```
    def filename = "${__counter(FALSE,)}" + "response.html";
    File file = new File("C://JmeterResultFolder//"+filename);
```

or this:
(Using Counter Sampler)

[image]

```
def filename = "${counter}" + "response.html";
File file = new File("C://JmeterResultFolder//"+filename);
```

and in the end you will get file for each request
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Should i put path including file name in 'pathToYourFile'? I tried entering the path without file name and got file not found exception. So what file extension should I put? Also will the above code save screen images like .jpg or  .png?

Comment: Yes, you should put file name in 'pathToYourFile'.  ' File file = new File("C:\\qqq\\zzz.html"); ' Folder 'qqq' must exist.     'FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file,false);' The second parameter must be "false", so that the files are overwritten. You can generate a name using the counter, just add the number to the name. In addition, you may have problems saving images, it depends on what kind of response you get

Comment: Sorry to hassle. it replaces the existing file due to same file name hence last step of the last controller is only captured. Can you please help to understand how to generate the name using counter? Or should I add this postprocessor under each step in the recording controller with unique name?

Comment: Thanks Sergey.. This exactly what I need. Before closing the question, can I ask you a last question? If I want to store the results with steps name under a recording controller then can I use ${stepname}?

Comment: @DivakarRagupathy Sorry, but I didn't understand what do you mean. You just want change variable name from ${counter} to ${stepname} ? If it what you need, you may change Reference name in counter.

Comment: I have added a screenshot for better understanding. Here what happened is, I have added JSR223 with your suggeted code at the end of my test plan hence it is storing only the last step of the last recording controller is only getting stored. But I want to store all step under each recording controller should be saved.

Comment: My sincere apologies.. I havent scroll down the html. this is more than enough to manage my project. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can user .csv file to store the response data. Please refer below screen

[Basic link for Listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-1-basic-display-formats)

[image: .csv File]

Comment: The csv file is fine but I want to store the screen images that are displayed in the view results tree. Please help on this

Comment: @DivakarRagupathy: one way is you can generate html report through command line. or you can take screen shots

Comment: @DivakarRagupathy: after generating CSV file you can use this comands Jmeter -g  "Location of CSV file " -O "Location of Out put file". any query let me know.

Comment: @DivakarRagupathy  welcome please select correct answer section will help full to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure JMeter to store response data if it is needed for any reason, add the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
```

and restart JMeter to pick the properties up. Next time you run your script response data will be inlined into .jtl results file and you will be able to see it with [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Results File Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

---

Be aware that storing response data causes massive disk IO overhead so use it wisely (i.e. for tests development and/or debugging only) as it might ruin your test given more or less high load.